# Check my workings for section formula

Tags: vectors

I do not have the answer to this question:

Find Point P if P divides in the ration 3:2 where A(2, -3) and B(7, 7).

So using the section formula:

${P = {{na + mb}\over{m + n}}}$

${P = {{2({2\over -3}) + 3 ({7\over 7})}\over 5}}$

${P = {{{({4\over -6})} + ({21\over 21})}\over 5}}$

${P = {1\over 5}({25\over 15})}$

${P= ({5\over 3})}$

=> (5, 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first coordinate is correct but the second coordinate should be 3.

You aren't using the formula properly. a should be your first coordinate of A and b is first coordinate of B.

Comment: you are correct, thanks.  I've fixed the question